# Azure App Service on Linux - Static File Content not updated

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created an App Service (inside Linux based App Service Plan). I have connected to wwwroot folder using FTP Client

1. In the hostingstaart.html, I made a simple text change.
2. I couldn't see the change getting reflected when I navigate to https://.azurewebsites.net/
3. However, when I navigate to Kudu and access the same page, I can see the change.

Below is the screenshot.
In the left hand side (kudu website), I can see the change that I have made (DevOps Engineers). However, In this right hand side, the changes is not shown.
In order to troubleshoot, I have added another file as well which is visible in Kudu. But, I'm not able to access the same.

This is not at all an issue in Windows Based App Service Plan. This is an issue only with Linux based app.
Is there any docker container internally where it reads the files from? if yes, how do change those files?

Appreciate any help here .

Thanks,
Praveen

[image]

Comment: Set the app settings ***WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE=0*** and ***WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION=Never*** to disable all file caching.

Comment: Based on your application framework, you need to add a startup cmd - expected values for the Startup File section.
***Navigate to your WebApp on Azure Portal > Settings > Configuration> General settings > Startup Command":***

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Azure App Service on Linux run in containers and depending on the platform, different webservers and locations are used which can get confusing.

For SSH access into the container go to `https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host` - in .NET projects on Linux the default page you'll see on a new app service is stored at `/defaulthome/hostingstart/wwwroot/hostingstart.html` while files you upload via FTP will go to `/home/site/wwwroot`.

That being said, I'd recommend to use the documented ways to publish content based on the platform you want to use. For .NET, you can find the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net60&pivots=development-environment-cli).